# Stopping download of file in Java applet

Tags: java, download, io

I wonder what is the most elegant and optimal way to stop downloading a file. I have a simple applet which is supposed to download requested files from user account at my website.

I would like to offer my users possibility to stop download at any moment. Simplet version of my code:

```
InputStream is = null;
FileOutputStream os = null;
os = new FileOutputStream(...);
URL u = new URL(...);
URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
is = uc.getInputStream();
final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
for(int count = is.read(buf);count != -1;count = is.read(buf)) {
    os.write(buf, 0, count);
}
```

My only idea is to define new variable e.g. MyStop, make it false and put in my loop instructions:

```
if(MyStop == true) { break; }
```

MyStop would be changing into true when user clicked the "Stop" button.

That's what I was thinking about but I am pretty sure that there is a better solution.

Thanks in advance.
Styler

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that idea.